# Presentation style of the summary table in R

Tags: r, summary

I am trying to have create a summary table in R like the one in Table 4 below.
[image]

Right now what I have is something like the one below. I am not sure how to automatically generate the Latex codes in R to create a table like the one in above.

[image]

I am using the following R codes to generate the table. Then I copy and paste the codes in Latex to get it to appear in the pdf.

```
#Build a rough summary table
summary1 <-
  list("Age (Years)" =
         list("Missing"  = ~ sum(is.na(df$age_years)),
              "Type" = ~ if(is.numeric(df$age_years)==TRUE) {print("Numeric")} else {print("Character")},
              "Min"       = ~ min(age_years),
              "Max"       = ~ max(age_years),
              "Mean" = ~ format(round(mean(df$age_years), 2), nsmall = 2),
              "SD" = ~ format(round(sd(df$age_years), 2), nsmall = 2)),
       "Female" =
         list("Missing"  = ~ sum(is.na(df$sex_DV)),
              "Type" = ~ if(is.numeric(df$sex_DV)==TRUE) {print("Numeric")} else {print("Character")},
              "Min"       = ~ min(sex_DV),
              "Max"       = ~ max(sex_DV),
              "Mean" = ~ format(round(mean(df$sex_DV), 2), nsmall = 2),
              "SD" = ~ format(round(sd(df$sex_DV), 2), nsmall = 2))
       )

whole <- summary_table(df,summary1)
whole
```

Any help would be welcome. Thanks!

**EDIT:** With reproducible part of the data (not the actual data)

```
> df
      age_years       sex
    1          33          0
    2          11          1
    3          45          1
    4          67          0
    5          8           0
    6          99          0
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your underlying data? You could `dput(df)` to output this

Comment: @EmilyKothe I put a short version of the df with only two variables. It's just how I want to display the table in the summary I guess

Comment: Where is the information for the label column stored? (i.e. are they stored as attribute for these variables?)

Comment: @EmilyKothe Oh that's from another dataset. It's more of an example. I am trying to follow that structure for now. I don't have the label column in my dataset so can avoid that part. I want to basically follow the ``wide dataset`` format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the example data provided, you could achieve the following.

```
df <- data.frame(
   age_years = c(33L, 11L, 45L, 67L, 8L, 99L),
         sex = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L)
)

names <- names(df)
missing_counts <- sapply(df, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))
classes <- sapply(df, function(x) class(x))
min <- sapply(df, function(x) min(x, na.rm = TRUE))
max <- sapply(df, function(x) max(x, na.rm = TRUE))
sd <- sapply(df, function(x) sd(x, na.rm = TRUE))
mean <- sapply(df, function(x) mean(x, na.rm = TRUE))

knitr::kable(as.data.frame(cbind(names, missing_counts, classes, min, max, mean, sd), row.names = FALSE))
```

| names | missing_counts | classes | min | max | sd | mean |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| age_years | 0 | integer | 8 | 99 | 34.8161839762296 | 43.8333333333333 |
| sex | 0 | integer | 0 | 1 | 0.516397779494322 | 0.333333333333333 |

*Sidenote, with gender coded as 0 and 1 you likely want this data to be a factor rather than numeric and you may not want to report a mean/SD for this statistic.*

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I agree with you on gender part. Btw is there a way to get R to spit out the codes for the latex table for this? With ``summary_table(df,summary1)`` it was easy to do so.